# Proving or Disproving statements using sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I just don't seem to get proofs or set theory so hopefully my question makes sense.

I'm not sure when I should or shouldn't use an example to prove or disprove a statement?

One example question is, if C $\subseteq$ A and D $\subseteq$ B, then C $\cup$ D $\subseteq$ A $\cup$ B.

I want start by making set A = $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ , B = $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ C = $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and D = $\{1,2,3,4\}$

and this would show an example proving this statement. However I think this might be wrong because it only shows one example.

So, I tried to think of a counterexample that would show that the statement is false. However I'm not sure if I should then try to prove, If C $\subseteq$ A and D $\subseteq$ B, then C $\cup$ D $\subseteq$ A $\cup$ B false or if I should be proving, If C $\subseteq$ A and D $\subseteq$ B, then C $\cup$ D $\subsetneq$ A $\cup$ B false??

I've also tried using x $\in$ C $\subseteq$ A, then x $\in$ C and x $\in$ A, x $\in$ D 
$\subseteq$ B, then x $\in$ D and x $\in$ B

But, I didn't know what to do from there.

Comment: It would show an example when the statement is true, but it doesn't prove it. Saying that your example proves the statement is like saying because $x+y=3$ has a solution, $1+2=3$, then for every $x,y$, $x+y=3$.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. So then I should try to use some other method to prove it or try and disprove it?

Comment: Examples work when you are trying to prove something like "there exists..." So if you wanted to prove: "There exists sets $A, B, C,$ and $D$ with $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$ such that $C\cup D\subseteq A\cup B$."

Comment: If you want to prove a "for all" question, an example doesn't suffice (because it only shows the statement is true for one case).

Comment: @TravisJ, ahhhh ok that makes sense. I get that, thanks

Comment: @TravisJ, I forgot to add the question actually starts "Let A, B, C and D be sets" so then sounds like a "there exists" type question? no?

Comment: It "means" let $A, B, C$, and $D$ be ANY set.  So the ANY implicitly means that it must be true for every such combination.

Comment: If the statement were false, then you could show it was false by giving one counter-example.  Since if the statement says it's true for every case, and you can show it isn't for at least one case, then it would be false.

Comment: @TravisJ, got it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, you are asked to prove a "for all" type question.  For all sets $A, B, C$, and $D$ with $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$ prove that $C\cup D\subseteq A\cup B$.

To show the containment, take an arbitrary element from the left and show that it is in the right.  For example, let $x\in C\cup D$, then either $x\in C$ or $x\in D$.  Without loss of generality, suppose that $x\in C$.  Then $x\in A$ since $C\subseteq A$ and hence $x\in A\cup B$.

Comment: sorry forgot to add the beginning of the question not sure if that changes anything?

Comment: nevermind for all sets. got it

Answer (score 0):

Your last approach is really the way to try to go--that is, proving most set properties requires some sort of "element-chasing" proof (unless you're allowed to use simple set algebra, but it does not look like you are quite there just yet). Consider the following element-chasing proof for your claim.

**Claim:** If $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$, then $C\cup D\subseteq A\cup B$.

*Proof.* Choose an arbitrary $x\in C\cup D$. Then, $x\in C$ or $x\in D$.

- If $x\in C$, then $x\in A$ since $C\subseteq A$; also, if $x\in A$, then surely $x\in A\cup B$.
- If $x\in D$, then $x\in B$ since $D\subseteq B$; also, if $x\in B$, then surely $x\in A\cup B$.

Either way, what you have shown is that
$$
x\in C\cup D\implies x\in A\cup B.
$$
That is all that is required to show one set is a subset of another set.

Comment: Thanks Crash that helps a lot!!!